# what exactly is that effect at http://bsonspec.org/#/faq?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know what exactly is that effect at http://bsonspec.org/#/faq ?

Like when you click a link, something cool happens (that can't be described with words).

it looks awesome, is anyone's eyes fast enough to see what exactly is happening step by step?

Comment: Simple jQuery `.hide()` and `.show()` with "fast" parameter. You can view the source, with Chrome it becomes easy task.

Comment: I don't see anything :(  Edit: oh, ok, it's not "when you click a link", it's "when you click a button" (even if they are links in reality)

Comment: @Shadow i do not use jquery. can you elaborate on the answer. do you mean this function: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Yes indeed, that one in addition to `.show()` are used. To have exactly this effect just use jQuery it's not really heavy and these days used by major part of the big websites. There are "pure JavaScript" ways as well if you insist, but can't see the point to look for those.

Answer (score 3):

It must be a JQuery effect : hide()

Comment: i do not use jquery. can you elaborate on the answer. do you mean this function: http://api.jquery.com/hide/